# Asymptotics of a Sequence Defined from Multinomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

I am trying to obtain asymptotic estimates for a sequence $A(n)$ defined by $$A(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k}{(n-k+1)(n+k)}{2n-k\choose n}{n+k\choose k\,,\,2k-1\,,\,n-2k+1}.$$ I'm not very familiar with asymptotics in combinatorics, so I don't really know if this is a manageable problem or if there is an easy solution that  don't know about. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you missing a $-1$ in the "numerator" of the multinomial coefficient?

Comment: Oops. No, but the $n-2k$ should be $n-2k+1$. I'll edit that.

Comment: One important datum to extract: given $n$, for which $k$ (roughly) is the summand largest? Probably the summands increase until some magic middle point $k$ and then decrease thereafter. One should be able to take the quotient of the $(k+1)$st summand over the $k$th summand and solve, at least approximately, for the value of $k$ that makes that quotient equal to $1$.

Comment: Apparently, $~\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{A(n)^2}{A(n-1)A(n+1)}=1$.

Comment: I took @GregMartin's advice, and I think I can show A(n) has exponential order at most 12.533. I can post something about this later when I work through the details.

Comment: Can you maybe undelete your Narayana question? I have established a proof.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry about that. I deleted it because I also found a proof, but I didn't think there was any interest in the question. I will undelete it and post my solution as well.